# Autocomplete based on values

Tags: django, django-models, autocomplete

I have an Mail app with User.auth,messages,contacts app which works smooth.and Every user has contact Ctaegory where they can add contact.now what i am trying to build an autocomplete in Recipeint field for making selection as the user type into a text box and the app should make search from contact category based on values client-side autocompleteion?

Comment: Good place to start: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light But really autocomplete is something that the interface does, the backend just has to supply a view that you can pass a search query to.